# Cannot connect 192.168.1.X from another local computer

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-7, local

I want to connect my apache server from another computer. But I cannot.

- My windows firewall is disabled.
- Other computer's firewall is disabled.
- My local ip address is 192.168.1.55
- Port is 80 of course.
- Both computer are windows.
- No antivirus softwares in both computers.

What can I do now? What is the problem?

Comment: *But I cannot.* - You need to tell us: **what happens when you try?**. Saying "but I cannot" can mean anything from it not working due to the reasons mentioned in Steve's superb answer below all the way through to the computer catching fire and exploding or aliens stealing your network cable.

Comment: I'm going to go with copper-thieving extra-terrestrials.

Comment: Since I was trying to connect to PC from Samsung Smart TV wireless, there is nothing happens when I try :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, lets make sure we actually have connectivity to the other machine.

From a command prompt do a ping to the other machine. (ping xx.xx.xx.xx) hopefully you should see a response.

If you don't we need to check a couple of things.

Firstly ensure the subnet mask of the two machines are correct, if they are on the same subnet, then the subnet masks should be the same, if they are on a different subnet, then make sure they both have valid gateways.

If that all checks out, then i suppose we should check to ensure apache is actually running on the second machine, this can be done either through the apache control panel that normally sits in the taskbar by the clock, or via services in administrators tools in control panel.

One thing of note, that has tripped me up in the past, if Skype is running on the same machine as apache, apache wont be able to bind to port 80.

**ADDED :**

I would also suggest you check your apache configuration to ensure it allows connections from servers other than localhost, if it's a development instance such as XAMPP it will be configured by default to only work locally, though this is easily changed.

Comment: All good diagnostic checks, I would also suggest you check your apache configuration to ensure it allows connections from servers other than localhost, if it's a development instance such as XAMPP it will be configured by default to only work locally, though this is easily changed.

Comment: Alex Berry, thanks I knew there was something like that but my google foo was weak :D

Comment: @Alex Berry, your suggestion worked. From Apache configuration, I change all Deny's with Allow's :) Thank you.

Comment: @AlexBerry This acceptance should be yours really...

Comment: @Steve No worries, you need the points :p though upvoting my comments would be good.